# Kendo Upload widget, how to bind it with asp.net 5 MVC 6 controller

Tags: file-upload, kendo-ui, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using kendo upload in MVVM pattern. Asp.net 5 MVC 6.

This is my code in the view. I bind this view to my viewmodel. It is showing the kendo Widget.

```
 <input name="files" id="uploadFile"
                           type="file"
                           class="files"
                           data-role="upload"
                           data-multiple="false"
                           data-async="{ saveUrl: 'UploadFile', removeUrl: 'remove', autoUpload: true }"
                           data-bind="visible: isVisible,
                                        enabled: isEnabled,
                                        events: { select: onSelect,
                                                  upload: onUpload,
                                                  cancel: onCancel,
                                                  error: onError,
                                                  complete: onComplete,
                                                  progress: onProgress,
                                                  remove: onRemove,
                                                  success: onSuccess}">
```

I have a action name UploadFile in my controller. As soon as I add the file I want it to upload the file. MVC 5 had "HttpPostedFileBase" to getthe file but in MVC 6 it is not there. I found some are saying to use IFormFile. I use it and still not working. I think I am having problem with binding. How can I bind the upload file so that when it hits the action I get the file and manipulate the file.

```
 public ActionResult UploadFile(IFormFile file){
 //Manipulate the file
 //Store in the database, whatever
 }
```

Raw Request would be

POST http://localhost:1234/Home/UploadFile HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:1234
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 1347
Origin: http://localhost:1234
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.101 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary1pEOGA0DgzseYnqE
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:1234/Documents/Add
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

Comment: Could you share how your raw request looks like, may be from Fiddler? (need not put the entire text content as it could be huge)

Comment: I am able to get the data,  I had input tag name="files" but in my action parameter was "file". But How you get the file data in bytes so that I can store the data in database??

Comment: you could read the stream like `new StreamReader(file.OpenReadStream())` to get the stream of the incoming file